# O <p:dataTable> não esta paginando

Tags: java-ee, jsf, xhtml

Te uma pagina que recebe um param.

```
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{MyBean.MyObject.id}" />
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{MyBean.exibir}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <c:set var="myobject" value="#{MyBean.MyObject.id}" scope="session"/>

    <h:form id="tabelaLancamentoid">
                <p:dataTable id="dataid" var="data" value="#{MyBean.All}"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                 paginator="true" rows="10" style="margin-bottom:20px">

                  <p:column headerText="Nome">
                  <h:outputText value="#{data.nome} " />
                  </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Meu MyBean

```
@Inject
FansubberDao dao;

private MyObjetc myObject = new MyObjetc(); 

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);

public void exibir(){
    if(myObject.getId()!=null)
        myObject = dao.getMyObjetc(myObject.getId());
}

public List<MyObjetc> getAll(){
    Integer id = (Integer)session.getAttribute("myobject");
    return dao.getAll(id);
}
```

Pagina exibe e monta normalmente a tabela toda vez que muda os parâmetro ID.
EX: se tabela pegar 50 registro e começa a navegar nas paginas, simplesmente some tudo.

Resolvi parte do problema pondo. c:if no c:set, a paginação funciona normalmente, problema e que agora se eu trocar o parâmetro id que chega na pagina por outro, ele fica a lista antiga.

```
<c:if test="#{sessionScope.myobject == null}">
    <c:set var="myobject" value="#{MyBean.MyObject.id}" scope="session"/>
</c:if>
```

Estou querendo uma solução para este problema.

Se tira o c:if a paginação não funciona corretamente, porem a toda vez que trocar o ID a nova tabela vem.
Se colocar o c:if a paginação funciona, porem a tabela não troca.

Teria de remover a variável myobject da sessão ou por ela em nulo, não sei como.
Tentei trabalhar com ViewScope porem a paginação não funciona corretamente.
Gostaria de uma solução que resolvesse os 2 problemas ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi os dois problemas

removi da pagina

```
<c:if test="#{sessionScope.myobject == null}">
    <c:set var="myobject" value="#{MyBean.MyObject.id}" scope="session"/>
</c:if>
```

alterei o:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{sessionScope.myobject}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{MyBean.exibir}" />
</f:metadata>
```

E alterei dois métodos exibir e getAll

```
public void exibir(){
    String id = (String)session.getAttribute("myobject");
    myObject = dao.getMyObjetc(Integer.parseInt(id));
}

public List<MyObjetc> getAll(){
    String id = (String)session.getAttribute("myobject");
    return dao.getAll(Integer.parseInt(id));
}
```